# ¿Cómo emular una matriz en Java?

Tags: java

¿Existe alguna forma de emular una matriz en Java **sin utilizar** propiamente arrays? De ser así, ¿cómo sería la forma de implementarlo?

Comment: Puedes usar List de List pero tendrias que llevar tu el control de toda la logica de posiciones. O incluso con un List solo siendo cada posicion el recorrido hacia la derecha y luego hacia abajo.

Comment: ¿Cuando dices "List de list" te refieres a utilizar una array list? No me ha quedado claro.

Comment: No. Un List<List<Object>>. Object lo cambias por el tipo necesario.

Comment: lo más fácil es, como tú has dicho, una array bidimensional, que es literalmente lo que quieres conseguir y es sencillo de trabajar.

Comment: Con las operaciones división y módulo, la implementación a partir de cualquier tipo de datos que se pueda acceder por índice es trivial. También es muy sencilla mediante mapas, con las coordenadas como clave (ya sea como tupla o como mapas anidados)... Y, si es de sólo lectura, se puede hacer hasta directamente por código. Me parece que es una pregunta demasiado amplia.

Answer (score 1):

Mi respuesta es NO. Los vectores (arrays) son un tipo de estructura de datos básica, puedes leer la [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(inform%C3%A1tica)) para tener una definición mas amplia. La mayoría de las demás estructuras como mapas, listas/listas enlazadas, pilas,  etc. están basados en vectores.

De todas la formas estas son algunas opciones (algunas son ridículamente estúpidas):

**Usando vectores:**

```
int n[][] = new int[3][3];
for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    for (int e = 0; e < n[i].lenght; e++) {
        n[i][e] = 1; // algun valor
    }
}
```

**Usando listas:**

```
List<List<Integer>> n = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    n.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    for (int e = 0; e < 4; e++) {
        n.get(i).add(e);
    }
}
```

**Usando mapas:**

```
Map<String, Integer> n = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

n.put("0,0", 2);
n.put("0,1", 4);
n.put("1,0", 5);
n.put("1,1", 5);

System.out.println(n.get("0,1"));
```

**Usando strings:** (esto también sirve como ejemplo de vector unidimensional)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<String> matrix = Arrays.asList("1,2,3,4,8,3,5,76,8".split(","));

    // suponiendo que largo = alto 
    System.out.println(get(matrix, 2, 1));
}

static int get(List<String> m, int x, int y){
    return Integer.parseInt(m.get(x + y * (int)Math.sqrt(m.size())));
}
```

Ahora si quieres ser extremo, imprime la matriz en una imagen y luego léelos con una librería de OCR como [Tesseract](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/). (aun así las imágenes están hechas de vectores de pixeles :P)

Answer (score 1):

Si no te convence un array de arrays como es común representar esto puedes probar la estructura de datos Table que te brinda la librería [Guava de Google](https://github.com/google/guava), está muy bien mantenida además que es fácil de usar.

Puedes acceder a ella fácilmente por Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

O descargando el jar [aquí](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/21.0/guava-21.0.jar).

Te dejo enlace de ejemplos desarrollados con esta librería:
http://www.baeldung.com/guava-table

Además el enlace a la documentación para su uso: http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html

Espero te sea de utilidad.